# UIButton won't go to Aspect Fit in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uibutton, aspect-fit

I have a couple UIButtons, and in IB they're set to Aspect Fit, but for some reason they're always stretching.  Is there something else you have to set?  I tried all the different view modes and none of them work, they all stretch.

Comment: @Werner Altesischer's answer is the right one. Make the appropriate changes.

Comment: @marty Are you setting background image or image? background image does not support it, only image.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've had that problem before. I solved it by putting my image in a `UIImageView`, where `contentMode` settings actually work, and putting a transparent custom `UIButton` over top of that.

EDIT: This answer is obsolete. See [@Werner Altewischer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995820/1953914) for the correct answer in modern versions of iOS.

Comment: Yeah tried that, but now can't get the button to refit to the image

Comment: How do you manage button states with this technique?  Seems like responding to user interaction like "highlighted" would be a nightmare.

Comment: This might have been the right way to do this 2.5 years ago when this question was answered, but now you can edit the UIButton's internal ImageView and set the the content mode there. See the answer by @Werner Altewischer

Answer (score 243):

The solution is to set the `contentMode` on the `imageView` property of the `UIButton`. The `UIButton` has to be created with custom type for this to work I believe (otherwise `nil` is returned for this property).

Comment: This worked for me: `[button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];`

Comment: This works for me also but if I set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted=YES, the image is stretched again when I tap on the button.

Comment: Set adjustImageWhenHighlighted to NO and supply an image yourself for the highlighted state instead

Comment: The stretching in adjustsImage has been eliminated in iOS 6.

Comment: In iOS 8, this actually doesn't work for me. The original answer (with placing an imageView behind a transparent button) works best.

Comment: in SWIFT:  `button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: in Swift du jour: `button.imageView!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit`

Comment: Is this possible within the storyboard designer, or must it be set in code?

Comment: Also, on iOS 11+, the content mode has to be set before the image. Otherwise it will only get its good shape after taping on it.

Comment: What might cause an image set as the image for a button to appear cut off? Text appears fine if put instead of image

Answer (score 63):

**This method worked for me very well.:**

In **Xib** select the button and set `user defined runtime attributes`:

- Key path: `self.imageView.contentMode`
- Type: `Number`
- Value: `1`

[image: Click here to see more clearly the solution]

> We use number because you cant use enum there. But the UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit is equal to 1.

Comment: This also updated the image in the interface builder during design time. Great solution.

Comment: Great solution, few code and works like a charm , the enum is based on content mode list items.

Comment: You can also add an extension to make it a bit easier:

`extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var imageContentMode: Int {
        get {return imageView?.contentMode.rawValue ?? 0}
        set {imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode(rawValue: newValue) ?? .scaleAspectFit}
    }
}`

Comment: Without 'self'  `imageView.contentMode` worked for me!

Answer (score 24):

If you are doing this in Interface Builder, you can use the Runtime attributes inspector to set this directly without any code.

Set your Key Path on the button to be "imageView.contentMode" with a type of "Number" and a value of "1" (or whichever mode you would like).

[image: imageview.contentMode = 1]

Answer (score 17):

Use button's imageView for contentMode. Not directly on the button itself.

```
homeButton.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
homeButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
homeButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
[homeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kPNGLogo] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 6):

*If you put the image in an `UIImageView` behind the button, you'll loose the built-in functionality of the `UIButton` class, such as `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` and `adjustsImageWhenDisabled`, and of course the ability to set different images for different states (without the hazzle of doing this yourself).*

If we want to have an image **unstreched for all control states**, one approuch is to get the image using `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation`, as in the following method:

```
- (UIImage *) getScaledImage:(UIImage *)img insideButton:(UIButton *)btn {

    // Check which dimension (width or height) to pay respect to and
    // calculate the scale factor
    CGFloat imgRatio = img.size.width / img.size.height, 
            btnRatio = btn.frame.size.width / btn.frame.size.height,
            scaleFactor = (imgRatio > btnRatio 
                           ? img.size.width / btn.frame.size.width
                           : img.size.height / btn.frame.size.height;

    // Create image using scale factor
    UIImage *scaledImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage]
                                             scale:scaleFactor
                                       orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return scaledImg;
}
```

To implement this we would write:

```
UIImage *scaledImg = [self getScaledImage:myBtnImg insideButton:myBtn];
[myBtn setImage:scaledImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This should prevent the image from stretching in all control states. It worked for me, but let me know if it doesn't!

**NOTE:** Here we are addressing a problem relating to `UIButton`, but the `insideButton:` might as well be `insideView:`, or whatever one would like to fit the image into.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem a while back. The issue I had was i was trying to apply this effect to the background UIButton which is limited and therefore means you cannot adjust it as easy.

The trick is to set it as just an image then apply @ayreguitar's technique and that should fix it!

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[myButton setImage:@"myImage.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
[button.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

Thanks to @ayreguitar for his comment

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative answer in swift:

```
myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 4):

Combining together a few different answers into one solution-- create a button with a custom type, set the button's imageView contentMode property, and set the image for the button (not the background image, which will still scale to fill).

```
//Objective-C:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:"myImageName.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//Swift:
let image = UIImage(named: "myImageName.png")
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

ios 12. 
You need to add also the content Alignment

```
class FitButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)


    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
        self.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
        super.layoutSubviews()


    }

}
```

Comment: Supposed to be aspect FIT not FILL

Answer (score 3):

```
btn.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11679579)

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is based on [@WernerAltewischer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995820/272342).*

To avoid having connect my button to an IBOutlet to execute the code on it, I subclassed UIButton's class:

```
// .h
@interface UIButtonWithImageAspectFit : UIButton
@end

// .m
@implementation UIButtonWithImageAspectFit

- (void) awakeFromNib {
    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}

@end
```

Now create a custom button in your xib, and set its image (not the background image):

[image: UIButtonWithImageAspectFit: create and set image]

Then, set its class:
[image: UIButtonWithImageAspectFit: set custom class]

You're done!
Instead of
[image: UIButton without image aspect fit]
your button's image aspect fit is now as expected:
[image: UIButton with image aspect fit]

Answer (score 1):

UIView content modes apply to the corresponding CALayer's "content". This works for `UIImageView`s because they set the `CALayer` content to the corresponding `CGImage`.

`drawRect:` ultimately renders to the layer content.

A custom `UIButton` (as far as I know) has no content (the rounded-rect style buttons might be rendered using content). The button has subviews: the background `UIImageView`, the image `UIImageView`, and the title `UILabel`. Setting the `contentMode` on the subviews may do what you want, but messing around with the `UIButton` view hierarchy is a bit of a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with the image not resizing proportionately so the way I fixed it was using edge insets.

```
fooButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 15, 10, 15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing `UIButton.imageView.contentMode` does not worked for me.
**I solved the problem by setting the image to 'Background' property.**
You can add ratio constraint if you need

Answer (score 1):

This overlaps many of the other answers, but the solution for me was to

- set the `contentMode` of the `UIImageView` for the button to `.ScaleAspectFit` – which can either be done in the ”User Defined Runtime Attributes” in Interface Builder (ie. `self.imageView.contentMode`, Number, 1) or in a `UIButton` subclass;
- disable ”Autoresize Subviews”;
- set ”Edge” to ”Image” and appropriate ”Top” and ”Bottom” values for ”Inset” (which might only be needed if you, like me, used a PDF as image).

Answer (score 0):

You can use imageWithCGImage as shown above (but without the missing parentheses).

Also... millions of non-4.0 phones won't work with that code at all.

Answer (score 0):

`[button sizeToFit]` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Guillaume, I have created a subclass of UIButton as a Swift-File. Then set my custom class in the Interface Builder:

[image: interface builder].

And here the Swift file:

```
import UIKit

class TRAspectButton : UIButton {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, but I couldn't get it to work (perhaps it's a bug with the SDK).

Eventually, as a workaround, I placed a `UIImageView` behind my button and set the options I wanted on that, then simply placed a blank `UIButton` on top of it.

Comment: Is there an echo in here? ;-)