# UIButton's backgroundImage's content mode not respected

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm putting the finishing touches on an app I'm about to publish and I've enountered difficulty getting the `contentMode` of a `UIButton`'s background image to be respected. Regardless of the `contentMode` I specify, the image just gets plopped in the background with no regard for the `contentMode` setting.

I've looked at a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3995820/4475605) covering this topic, but it doesn't appear to do anything in my circumstance.

This is called in from `viewDidLoad`:

```
// I tried putting the contentMode lines here...
myButton.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
myButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), for: .normal)

// ...and here
// myButton.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
// myButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

// I threw this in for S's & G's to see if it would work...it didn't
myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
myButton.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I rest assured it will be something startling stupid on my part. I welcome suggestions on how I can get the `contentMode` of a `UIButton`'s background image to be respected. Thank you for reading.

**Update**

The button is typed as a custom button, not a system button.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that you add an image using `setBackgroundImage()` method. This adds your image to some private `UIImageView` that you can't reach directly like `myButton.imageView!`. In your code, you're applying `contentType` for you button instead of its background image.

If you want to reach this background `UIImageView` you need to use `subviews` array. But if you try to do this inside your `viewDidLoad()` method, you'll find that background `UIImageView` hasn't been added yet because your buttons `layout` method wasn't called. There are 2 ways to fix that.

**Solution 1** – call `layoutIfNeeded` explicitly:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "myImage"), for: .normal)
    myButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    myButton.subviews.first?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

**Solution 2** – move `contentMode` setup at `viewDidAppear` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "myImage"), for: .normal)
    myButton.setTitle("Some title", for: .normal)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    myButton.subviews.first?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 13):

To simplify the accepted answer, all you need to do is layout the subviews and your setup code can be done in one place.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), for: .normal)
    myButton.layoutIfNeeded()
    myButton.subviews.first?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A button's imageView property and backgroundImage property are two separate things.

Unlike the accepted answer, you can use the imageView property instead.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), for: .normal)
   myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```