# scale type or contentMode of Image in UIButton is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was trying to put an image in UIButton and the image would fill up the space keeping the aspect ratio intact. I was not able to apply the content mode. Please see the screenshot[image]

I also tried from the code and it's not working as well

```
myButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

By changing the alignment, the image takes the whole space but it does not keep the aspect ratio and content mode does not work as well.

Comment: set image as a background image in the attributes inspector.

Comment: System Image/Icons will not Work. you can use your own image of large size.

Comment: @KumarLav I tried with asset image as well. it did not work

Comment: @SAXENA how i will apply contentmode with background image?

Comment: @sadat https://stackoverflow.com/a/40247470/8687925

Comment: please read this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093769/8687925

Comment: Hope this will help you,
https://github.com/devxoul/UIButton-BackgroundContentMode

Answer (score 0):

What's causing your problem is how small the image is. There are two things you can do. One option is to set the image you have now as the background image and then change the button's constraints to get the proportions right. You won't be able to have the button be the size you have it now, though, because the image will be all stretched out.

The other thing you could do is find a bigger or different image of that symbol (square.and.arrow), rather than using the one already loaded into Xcode.