# dynamic button with images

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a `UIView` which contains a `UIStackView` with some buttons. Here bellow I represent the schema that conforms my case:

[image]

The problem comes when you give a dynamic size to the superview, then buttons start distorting like the image bellow:

[image]

Any help with this?

Finally I got the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460694/uibutton-wont-go-to-aspect-fit-in-iphone/3995820#3995820) post

Comment: Add constraints to you button.

Comment: @Shebuka giving an aspect ratio to 1:1 for each button solves my problem, but I was looking for something much more clean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIButton content mode as Aspect Fit for resolve image distorting issue.